# Errors after installing PHP script

Tags: php

Brand new to all of this and trying to install my PHP script. When I enter my url, I get the following errors:

> Warning: mysql_pconnect() [function.mysql-pconnect]: Access denied for
>   user 'god'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in
>   /home/cbstacy/public_html/dirtytwenty.com/libraries/adodb/drivers/adodb-mysql.inc.php
>   on line 227
>
> Warning: mysql_real_escape_string()
>   [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user
>   'cbstacy'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in
>   /home/cbstacy/public_html/dirtytwenty.com/include/config.php on line
>   140
>
> Warning: mysql_real_escape_string()
>   [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: A link to the server could not be
>   established in
>   /home/cbstacy/public_html/dirtytwenty.com/include/config.php on line
>   140

Comment: Seems to be a MySQL permission problem. Make sure the user has the correct rights on the database, and that you're passing the right credentials. Also, it seems strange that the first warning mentions `'god'@'localhost'`, while the second one mentions `'cbstacy'@'localhost'`. Are you trying to do two separate connections, with two different users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's merely a "wrong username or password" situation. Review your DB connection data.

Strangely, it also seems your script is trying to connect to the DB using two different users.

Comment: Hmm,

Ok I'll see if I can figure out whats going on. Thank you

Comment: Still having the same issues. Really stuck here. I'm sure it's a simple fix.

Comment: I'm sad I can't help you without knowing how the script works.